# Overriding CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS reducer for non-immediate deletes

Tags: admin-on-rest

Right now admin-on-rest deletes a resource from its local state when it issues a `DELETE` API call. So it vanishes from the UI even before its refresh its state with a `GET`. This is cool.

Sometimes a delete operation isn't immediate, though. Real world example would be AWS - deleting an EC2 instance takes time. Deleting an RDS instance takes 15 minutes. Deleting a cloudfront instance takes even longer.

For a subset of my API's i want the `DELETE` button to update the local state (field 'state' becomes 'deleting') rather than removing it.

Looking at [this commit](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/commit/cd5a5a9e95f013cd929cfe6398fed7f603ce9d3d), all `CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS` lead to resources getting removed from the list.

I think I could implement a custom action and button (and possibly there is more copy-pasta to add a confirmation page?) but i'm not sure how I would update the local state - apparently that happens automatically for the `fetch: UPDATE` action?

Does anyone have any ideas on the 'right' way to do this in admin-on-rest?

Comment: It's frustrating that `crudDelete` is something that can be set on a `<Delete>` but there is now way to surface that.

Comment: You can try and open an issue. If they like your ideas then they do listen. Or atleast provide a clear justification as to why they are not listening.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a custom saga too. In it, handle your custom delete action with the logic needed to check whether it has completed. When it does, dispatch the `CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS` with the expected data (you'll have to explore the code).

Comment: But if i dispatch `CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS` won't i actually trigger the very bit of code I was trying to avoid triggering?

Answer (score 0):

You can always strap on custom actions with AOR. DELETING can be an action dispatched by your component.

You can assign a Reducer to perform state changes when it sees DELETING (set record state to deleting)
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Actions.html#using-a-custom-reducer

A saga can redirect your users to the Holding page .

AOR will shoot a DELETING_SUCCESS when deletion action is completed and DELETING_FAILURE otherwise. You can use this to show a notification depending on the notification status.

You basically handle this entire cycle bypassing the existing logic.

Comment: That's roughly the direction i've been trying to go in - but it seems like a hell of a lot of copy and paste and duplication.

Comment: I don't really know if it will be a lot of copy pasting as long as your data flow is custom (and separate ) from aor. If you want to join the regular flow at any point then you can shoot the CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS/FAILURE (as indicated by @gildas) from a custom action as well and join the regular flow.

Comment: But if i fire a `CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS` won't I trigger the list reducer? (see [here](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/commit/cd5a5a9e95f013cd929cfe6398fed7f603ce9d3d)

Comment: You don't really have to fire the action, you can if you need. You can also fire another action on success and redirect your app using a custom Saga.